# Does Python-Requests support OrderedDicts, or is something else going wrong here?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to POST a request to an Amazon S3 endpoint using Python's [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. The request is of the multipart/form-data variety, because it includes the POSTing of an actual file.

One requirement specified by the API I'm working against is that the `file` parameter must be posted *last*. Since Requests uses dictionaries to POST multipart/form-data, and since dictionaries don't follow a dictated order, I've converted it into an OrderedDict called `payload`. It looks something like this before POSTing it:

```
{'content-type': 'text/plain',
 'success_action_redirect':     'https://ian.test.instructure.com/api/v1/files/30652543/create_success?uuid=<opaque_string>',
 'Signature': '<opaque_string>',
 'Filename': '',
 'acl': 'private',
 'Policy': '<opaque_string>',
 'key': 'account_95298/attachments/30652543/log.txt',
 'AWSAccessKeyId': '<opaque_string>',
 'file': '@log.txt'}
```

And this is how I POST it:

```
r = requests.post("https://instructure-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/", files = payload)
```

The response is a 500 error, so I'm really not sure what the issue is here. I'm just guessing that it has to do with my use of OrderedDict in Requests—I couldn't find any documentation suggesting Requests does or doesn't support OrderedDicts. It could be something completely different.

Does anything else stick out to you that would cause the request to fail? I could provide more detail if need be.

***Okay, update, based on Martijn Pieters' earlier comments:***

I changed the way I'm referencing the log.txt file by adding it to the already created `upload_data` dictionary like this:

```
upload_data['file'] = open("log.txt")
```

pprinting the resulting dictionary I get this:

```
{'AWSAccessKeyId': '<opaque_string>',
 'key': '<opaque_string>',
 'Policy': '<opaque_string>',
 'content-type': 'text/plain',
 'success_action_redirect': 'https://ian.test.instructure.com/api/v1/files/30652688/create_success?uuid=<opaque_string>',
 'Signature': '<opaque_string>',
 'acl': 'private',
 'Filename': '',
 'file': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='log.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>}
```

Does that value for the `file` key look correct?

When I post it to a RequestBin I get this, which looks pretty similar to Martin's example:

```
POST /1j92n011 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: python-requests/1.1.0 CPython/3.3.0 Darwin/12.2.0
Host: requestb.in
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Length: 2182
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: identity, gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*

--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"; filename="AWSAccessKeyId"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<opaque_string>
--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"; filename="key"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<opaque_string>
--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Policy"; filename="Policy"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<opaque_string>
--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content-type"; filename="content-type"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

text/plain
--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_redirect"; filename="success_action_redirect"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

https://ian.test.instructure.com/api/v1/files/30652688/create_success?uuid=<opaque_string>
--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Signature"; filename="Signature"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<opaque_string>
--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"; filename="acl"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

private
--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"; filename="Filename"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="log.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

This is my awesome test file.
--e8c3c3c5bb9440d1ba0a5fe11956e28d--
```

However, I still get a 500 returned when I try to POST it to https://instructure-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/. I've tried just adding the open file object to `files` and then submitting all the other values in a separate dict through `data`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in either a `dict`, *or* a sequence of two-value tuples.

And `OrderedDict` is trivially converted to such a sequence:

```
r = requests.post("https://instructure-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/", files=payload.items())
```

However, because the `collections.OrderedDict()` type is a subclass of `dict`, calling `items()` is *exactly* what `requests` does under the hood, so passing in an `OrderedDict` instance directly Just Works too.

As such, something else is wrong. You can verify what is being posted by posting to `http://httpbin/post` instead:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", files=payload.items()).json())
```

Unfortunately, `httpbin.org` does not preserve ordering. Alternatively, you can create a dedicated HTTP post bin at http://requestb.in/ as well; it'll tell you in more detail what goes on.

Using requestb.in, and by replacing `'@log.txt'` with an open file object, the POST from requests is logged as:

```
POST /tlrsd2tl HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: python-requests/1.1.0 CPython/2.7.3 Darwin/11.4.2
Host: requestb.in
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Length: 1601
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*

--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content-type"; filename="content-type"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

text/plain
--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_redirect"; filename="success_action_redirect"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

https://ian.test.instructure.com/api/v1/files/30652543/create_success?uuid=<opaque_string>
--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Signature"; filename="Signature"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<opaque_string>
--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"; filename="Filename"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"; filename="acl"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

private
--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Policy"; filename="Policy"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<opaque_string>
--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"; filename="key"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

account_95298/attachments/30652543/log.txt
--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"; filename="AWSAccessKeyId"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<opaque_string>
--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="log.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

some
data

--7b12bf345d0744b6b7e66c7890214311--
```

showing that ordering is preserved correctly.

Note that `requests` does not support the Curl-specific `@filename` syntax; instead, pass in an open file object:

```
 'file': open('log.txt', 'rb')
```

You may also want to set the `content-type` field to use title case: `'Content-Type': ..`.

If you still get a 500 response, check the `r.text` response text to see what Amazon thinks is wrong.

Comment: So you're saying the problem isn't with my use of an OrderedDict, correct?

Comment: @IanMorris: Correct, sorry, I was called away mid-post.

Comment: @IanMorris: Is your file field meant to contain `'@log.txt'`? If you need to stream a local file named `log.txt` you need to replace that with an open file object.

Comment: Ah you could be exactly right there. I'm translating the API's curl example into Python, and that's the syntax used there. I'll take a look.

Comment: @IanMorris: ah, `requests` does *not* support the Curl `@filename` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, @MartijnPieters. I updated my post with what I'm seeing now.

Comment: @IanMorris: What is the error response? `print(r.text)` should tell you more.

Comment: @IanMorris: I wasn't aware you are on Python 3; I'd open the file in binary mode in that case, `open('log.txt', 'rb')` and save decoding and encoding again.

Comment: It's just a generic "Oops! Something went wrong!" HTML page from instructure.com. The header shows an HTTP status of 500. I'm assuming that Amazon is using the `success_action_redirect` value to send me over to instructure.com, but Instructure isn't a fan of how it's being sent or something. Also, `content-type` is a key pulled from a previous request to Instructure's API, but I suppose I could try updating it to title case before using it for the second response.

Comment: @IanMorris: Ah, right, so it is not Amazon S3 that is throwing the error. Note that in that case your request itself seems to work as Amazon is redirecting you.

Comment: @MartinPieters: Would it be more appropriate for me to continue this question in a new post now since the question of `OrderedDicts` has been answered? Or is there even anything more that you or others here could add? Seems to me like I may need to get in touch with the Instructure folks to see could be wrong...

Comment: @IanMorris: I've helped all I can with your original question, yes. You could try a new question, but I personally think this is a Instructure problem. :-)

Comment: No this is an issue with how @IanMorris is using the requests API.

Answer (score 3):

You need to split what you're sending into an OrderedDict passed to `data` and one sent to `files`. Right now AWS is (correctly) interpretting your data parameters as FILES, not as form paramaters. It should look like this:

```
data = OrderedDict([
    ('AWSAccessKeyId', '<opaque_string>'),
    ('key', '<opaque_string>'),
    ('Policy', '<opaque_string>'),
    ('content-type', 'text/plain'),
    ('success_action_redirect', 'https://ian.test.instructure.com/api/v1/files/30652688/create_success?uuid=<opaque_string>'),
    ('Signature', '<opaque_string>'),
    ('acl', 'private'),
    ('Filename', ''),
])

files = OrderedDict([('file', open('log.txt'))])

requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```